# conda init bash doesn't work into github actions

Tags: bash, conda, github-actions

I want to activate conda environment and install some packages in github actions. I tried `source activate myenv` and `activate myenv` but this step doesn't activate anything

```
upload_package(){
    conda config --set anaconda_upload yes
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y build-essential
    conda init bash
    conda create -n myenv python=3.6
    conda activate myenv
    echo $PWD
    echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
    conda install --yes pip
    conda install --yes numpy cython
    conda install --yes -c conda-forge nose mdtraj  
    anaconda login --username $INPUT_ANACONDAUSERNAME --password $INPUT_ANACONDAPASSWORD
    echo $PWD
    echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
    conda build /github/workspace 
    anaconda logout
}
```

i tried to check with `echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"` but it either gives empty screen (`source activate myenv` and `activate myenv`) or just gives an error below. I don't know how can i handle as I don't know how can I restart and close shell as it is on github actions. I would appreciate your help

```
2020-03-04T10:50:25.2340743Z + conda init bash
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3835655Z no change     /opt/conda/condabin/conda
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3836003Z no change     /opt/conda/bin/conda
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3836764Z no change     /opt/conda/bin/conda-env
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3836919Z no change     /opt/conda/bin/activate
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3837068Z no change     /opt/conda/bin/deactivate
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3837223Z no change     /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3837381Z no change     /opt/conda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3837539Z no change     /opt/conda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3837904Z no change     /opt/conda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3838273Z no change     /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3838453Z no change     /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3838607Z modified      /github/home/.bashrc
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3838685Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3839039Z ==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
2020-03-04T10:50:25.3839151Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:25.4034555Z + conda create -n myenv python=3.6
2020-03-04T10:50:25.9277471Z Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
2020-03-04T10:50:25.9642682Z Solving environment: ...working... done
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490197Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490460Z ## Package Plan ##
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490535Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490685Z   environment location: /opt/conda/envs/myenv
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490781Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0490926Z   added / updated specs:
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0491662Z     - python=3.6
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0491756Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0491824Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0491969Z The following packages will be downloaded:
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0492062Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0492460Z     package                    |            build
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0492845Z     ---------------------------|-----------------
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0493211Z     _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |             main           3 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0493583Z     certifi-2019.11.28         |           py36_0         153 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0493961Z     ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1    |       h53a641e_7         568 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0494323Z     libedit-3.1.20181209       |       hc058e9b_0         163 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0494679Z     libffi-3.2.1               |       hd88cf55_4          40 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0495035Z     libgcc-ng-9.1.0            |       hdf63c60_0         5.1 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0495392Z     libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0         |       hdf63c60_0         3.1 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0495732Z     ncurses-6.2                |       he6710b0_0         1.1 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0496087Z     pip-20.0.2                 |           py36_1         1.7 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0496448Z     python-3.6.10              |       h0371630_0        29.7 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0496812Z     readline-7.0               |       h7b6447c_5         324 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0497169Z     setuptools-45.2.0          |           py36_0         520 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0497519Z     sqlite-3.31.1              |       h7b6447c_0         1.1 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0497879Z     tk-8.6.8                   |       hbc83047_0         2.8 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0498229Z     wheel-0.34.2               |           py36_0          51 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0498579Z     xz-5.2.4                   |       h14c3975_4         283 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0498931Z     zlib-1.2.11                |       h7b6447c_3         103 KB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0499273Z     ------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0499450Z                                            Total:        46.7 MB
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0499541Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0499681Z The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0499758Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0500489Z   _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0501110Z   ca-certificates    pkgs/main/linux-64::ca-certificates-2020.1.1-0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0501722Z   certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2019.11.28-py36_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0502345Z   ld_impl_linux-64   pkgs/main/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_7
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0502969Z   libedit            pkgs/main/linux-64::libedit-3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0503577Z   libffi             pkgs/main/linux-64::libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0504179Z   libgcc-ng          pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0504791Z   libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0505394Z   ncurses            pkgs/main/linux-64::ncurses-6.2-he6710b0_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0506278Z   openssl            pkgs/main/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_4
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0506910Z   pip                pkgs/main/linux-64::pip-20.0.2-py36_1
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0507509Z   python             pkgs/main/linux-64::python-3.6.10-h0371630_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0508111Z   readline           pkgs/main/linux-64::readline-7.0-h7b6447c_5
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0508708Z   setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-45.2.0-py36_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0509475Z   sqlite             pkgs/main/linux-64::sqlite-3.31.1-h7b6447c_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0510365Z   tk                 pkgs/main/linux-64::tk-8.6.8-hbc83047_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0510964Z   wheel              pkgs/main/linux-64::wheel-0.34.2-py36_0
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0511551Z   xz                 pkgs/main/linux-64::xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_4
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0512141Z   zlib               pkgs/main/linux-64::zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0512229Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0512313Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0512447Z Proceed ([y]/n)? 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0519068Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0519270Z Downloading and Extracting Packages
2020-03-04T10:50:26.0519494Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.1318915Z libedit-3.1.20181209 | 163 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.1319506Z libedit-3.1.20181209 | 163 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.1319646Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.3010399Z libgcc-ng-9.1.0      | 5.1 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.3016426Z libgcc-ng-9.1.0      | 5.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.3016551Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4178401Z tk-8.6.8             | 2.8 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4189777Z tk-8.6.8             | 2.8 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4190390Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4512708Z zlib-1.2.11          | 103 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4513072Z zlib-1.2.11          | 103 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4513153Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4688184Z _libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4694660Z _libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.4694795Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.8854186Z ncurses-6.2          | 1.1 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.8854823Z ncurses-6.2          | 1.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.8854969Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9238174Z ld_impl_linux-64-2.3 | 568 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9238718Z ld_impl_linux-64-2.3 | 568 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9238853Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9544406Z libffi-3.2.1         | 40 KB     |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9545028Z libffi-3.2.1         | 40 KB     | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9545172Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9767359Z certifi-2019.11.28   | 153 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9773520Z certifi-2019.11.28   | 153 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:26.9773720Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1019191Z pip-20.0.2           | 1.7 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1019873Z pip-20.0.2           | 1.7 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1020024Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1284184Z wheel-0.34.2         | 51 KB     |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1284729Z wheel-0.34.2         | 51 KB     | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1284982Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1635023Z xz-5.2.4             | 283 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1635574Z xz-5.2.4             | 283 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1635690Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1957966Z readline-7.0         | 324 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1958452Z readline-7.0         | 324 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.1958592Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.2419085Z sqlite-3.31.1        | 1.1 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.2419569Z sqlite-3.31.1        | 1.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.2419671Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.3421516Z python-3.6.10        | 29.7 MB   |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.4422601Z python-3.6.10        | 29.7 MB   | ##4        |  24% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.9656988Z python-3.6.10        | 29.7 MB   | #######    |  71% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.9657727Z python-3.6.10        | 29.7 MB   | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:27.9657877Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.0623746Z libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0   | 3.1 MB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.0624544Z libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0   | 3.1 MB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.0624701Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.1067800Z setuptools-45.2.0    | 520 KB    |            |   0% 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.1068596Z setuptools-45.2.0    | 520 KB    | ########## | 100% 
2020-03-04T10:50:28.3879641Z Preparing transaction: ...working... done
2020-03-04T10:50:29.1497815Z Verifying transaction: ...working... done
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7835172Z Executing transaction: ...working... done
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7902932Z #
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903104Z # To activate this environment, use
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903242Z #
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903364Z #     $ conda activate myenv
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903502Z #
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903644Z # To deactivate an active environment, use
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903785Z #
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7903919Z #     $ conda deactivate
2020-03-04T10:50:29.7904010Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:29.9029429Z + conda activate myenv
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0185463Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0186577Z CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0186790Z To initialize your shell, run
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0186898Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0187066Z     $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0187175Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0187334Z Currently supported shells are:
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0187683Z   - bash
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0188017Z   - fish
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0188343Z   - tcsh
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0188668Z   - xonsh
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0188995Z   - zsh
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0189331Z   - powershell
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0189418Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0189810Z See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0190158Z 
2020-03-04T10:50:30.0190604Z IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Comment: Instead of `conda init`, try `source <path to conda>/bin/activate`

Comment: still not working unfortunately. to be clear: `echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"` still returns empty string. Maybe it is something with github actions?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while trying to activate the conda env. I small change to the command mentioned by @FlyingTeller, is to use something like

```sh
conda create -n <YOUR_ENV_NAME> python=3.6
conda info         
$CONDA/bin/activate <YOUR_ENV_NAME>  # to activate the env
```

It is an old question without an answer, but anyone like me who faced this issue recently can try the above solution.